# Bind a LINQ query to FastReport and get only one row of data

Tags: c#, linq, fastreport

In the following code, when I click on the button, it will show all the records in the User table instead on giving me a single one which has (UserID == 17).

```
 ReGdbEntities re = new ReGdbEntities();
 private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Report report = new Report();
     string fileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Reports\Untitled.frx";
     var jfja = re.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == 17);
     report.RegisterData(jfja.ToList(), "User");
     report.GetDataSource("User").Enabled = true;
     report.Load(fileName);
     report.Prepare();
     report.Preview = this.previewControl1;
     report.Show();
 }
```

Comment: is this the full code or the shortened? What is `re` and where does it come from?

Comment: @VladL i will add it

Comment: @VladL its full code

Comment: What is ReGdbEntities? What is the type of `Users`?

Comment: IT is entity framework connection string for the database, Users is a table

Comment: What kind of table? It can not be a DataTable as it doesn't offer the `Where` extension method

Comment: its is a ms sql server, mdf file

Comment: No, I mean what is the type of the property `Users`. Make a right click on Users and then `Go to definition` then paste the definiton line here

Comment: public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

Comment: Check if the database table has more than one record for the same userid. If it has more than one record then you have to delete it, else if you just need the first record var jfja = re.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == 17).FindFirstOrDefault();

Comment: @user1511304 there is no FindFirstOrDefault() but there is FirstOrDefault() which does not work

Comment: If you use FirstOrDefault() what is happening, are you getting any error ?

Comment: if i use it, the { report.RegisterData(jfja.FirstOrDefault(), "User");} will be underlined as error

Comment: @r.salih can you tell us what the result of `re.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == 17).ToString()` is?

Comment: @DavidSherret it shows all the records again

Comment: @R.salih no, that will output the sql query that's being run. Could you provide that to us?

Comment: {SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
    [Extent1].[privilege] AS [privilege]
    FROM [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 17 = [Extent1].[UserID]}

Comment: @R.salih ok, I thought maybe UserID might not have been mapped properly for some reason. It's fine though.

Answer (score 1):

There should be more than one record in the table with the same ID 17 in your database.

If you need only the first record of the search result then you can use FirstOrDefault method.

```
var jfja = re.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == 17).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: there was the same answer but some good guys removed becasue report.RegisterData(FirstOrDefault, "User") does not accept single